# Windows BLE indication confirmation

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy

I can succesfully receive notification or indications from gatt server using my Windows Universal Platform program.

My question is how one confirms received indication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If indication is used it will be confirmed by BLE protocol design. If notification is used, you have to design your own top level protocol in order to confirm it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows's BLE stack will automatically send the confirmation and then deliver the indication to your app.